# Exception when creating an RKConnectionDescription with initWithRelationship:attributes:

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am having an interesting problem with RestKit. I want to be able to map my objects by their uniqueIDs in CoreData. It looks like RKConnectionDescription should allow me to do just that. I want to set up a connection between a RegisteredUser and a BasicModel object. The thing is that when I create the connection I receive an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` because RestKit says, `Cannot connect relationship: invalid attributes given for source entity 'RegisteredUser'`

Below is the code I have to create the mapping for the user.

```
RKEntityMapping *userEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"RegisteredUser" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[userEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"uniqueID",
                                                   @"createdAt",
                                                   @"updatedAt",
                                                   @"firstName",
                                                   @"middleName",
                                                   @"lastName",
                                                   @"email",
                                                   @"gender",
                                                   @"dateOfBirth",
                                                   @"profileImageUpdatedAt"]];
NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RegisteredUser" inManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *basicModelRelationship = [userEntity relationshipsByName][@"basicModel"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:basicModelRelationship attributes:@{@"basicModel": @"uniqueID"}];
[userEntityMapping addConnection:connection];
```

In core data a `RegisteredUser` has a one to one relationship with a `BasicModel` entity called `basicModel`. Additionally the `BasicModel` entity has a uniqueID attribute.

As far as I can figure, I am creating the RKConnectionDescription correctly according to the example [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html). The problem is that when I call `initWithRelationship:attributes:`, it asserts that there is a `basicModel` attribute on the `RegisteredUser` entity, which of course the isn't. There is only a `basicModel` relationship and so I get the crash I described above.

Why does RestKit even check that the `RegisteredUser` has an attribute `basicModel` if it expects me to be creating a connection for a relationship? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your JSON nested? Or is the connection made following 2 different responses (foreign key mapping)?

Comment: In attempting to map with a foreign key. JSON will look like the following when a user is requested. {results:{firstname:"Blah", lastName:"Blahblah", basicModel:3, etc...}, where 3 is the uniqueID of the basicModel managed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `RKConnectionDescription` is correct, but how you're using it is wrong. In this line:

```
initWithRelationship:basicModelRelationship attributes:@{@"basicModel": @"uniqueID"}];
```

you are telling RestKit about the relationship, but that it should use an attribute named `basicModel` in the `RegisteredUser` entity to find the `BasicModel` to connect to, matching the value of `basicModel` in the `RegisteredUser` with `uniqueID` in the `BasicModel`.

So, it is `basicModel` that needs to change. You need to add an attribute, like `basicModelId` to the `RegisteredUser` entity. It can be transient. Add it to the `RegisteredUser` mapping and use `basicModelId` in the `RKConnectionDescription`.

Comment: I see, that seems kind of goofy that I have to define an attribute for every relationship that my objects have. Do you know what the purpose of the attribute is? Should I just go with the nested dictionary approach, I have the ability to alter my REST API. Can I also use the foreign key of a nested object to map my objects in CoreData. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It's how foreign key mapping works, so not for every relationship. If you have nested JSON then you have no need for foreign key mapping.

Comment: Hmm so then if I used nested JSON and only included the "uniqueID" field in the nested JSON, would all of the other fields be assumed to be null and overwritten in CoreData? Or will it just update the attributes I include in the JSON?

Comment: By default it will only update data that is there. You need to set a flag to have non-present key values nilled out.